# React Native - check the render method of Screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

**Hello everyone,**

I'm trying to make an example of React Native tabs but whenever I try to put some `react-native-elements` into the component, it gives me an error. I researched and found a number of people who are facing this error but it didn't help me.

**Here is my PostScreen**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import styles from '../styles';

export default class PostScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      seed: 1,
      page: 1,
      users: [],
      isLoading: false,
      isRefreshing: false,
    };

   }

 handleRefresh = () => {
   this.setState({
   seed: this.state.seed + 1,
   isRefreshing: true,
 }, () => {
   this.loadUsers();
 });
};

handleLoadMore = () => {
   this.setState({
    page: this.state.page + 1
    }, () => {
    this.loadUsers();
   });
 };

 componentDidMount() {
   this.loadUsers();
 };

loadUsers = () => {
const { users, seed, page } = this.state;
this.setState({ isLoading: true });

fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      users: page === 1 ? res.results : [...users, ...res.results],
      isRefreshing: false,
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
};

render() {
  const list = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    avatar_url: 
   'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice President'
   },
  {
     name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
  }
 ]

return (
  <List containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
    {
      list.map((l) => (
        <ListItem
          roundAvatar
          avatar={{ uri: l.avatar_url }}
          key={l.name}
          title={l.name}
        />
      ))
    }
  </List>
 )
}
```

**Here is my App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

import {
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';

import PostScreen from './src/screens/PostScreen';
import WelcomeScreen from './src/screens/WelcomeScreen';


class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return <AppNavigator />
   }
}
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
   WelcomeScreen: {
       screen: WelcomeScreen,
       navigationOptions: {
       tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
           <Icon name="home" size={25} color={tintColor} />
   } 
 },
    Posts: {
       screen: PostScreen,
       navigationOptions: {
         tabBarLabel: 'PostScreen',
         tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) =>
           <Icon name="chart-bar" size={25} color={tintColor} />
       }
    }
 },
 {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'orange',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray'
    }
 }
 );

 export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

It works without any `react-native-elements` (List , Flatlist). With normal tags like Text, it works well.

[image: The error image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you are getting that error is that you are importing the `List` component which is not available in `react-native-elements`.

All you have to do it remove that `List` import and replace it with `View` component inside your render method.

Here's your edited code:

```
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class PostScreen extends React.Component {
// above code...

render() {
  const list = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    avatar_url: 
   'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice President'
   },
  {
     name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman'
  }
 ];

return (
  <View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
    {
      list.map((l) => (
        <ListItem
          roundAvatar
          avatar={{ uri: l.avatar_url }}
          key={l.name}
          title={l.name}
        />
      ))
    }
  </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: Yeap it worked but at the page https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/lists.html here says import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'

Comment: @erdemgunenc the docs you are referring to are for version `0.19.1` and in the latest version `1.1.0` it no longer exist.

Comment: Ahh my bad, thank you for your fast response help :)